# MOTD not showing on 18.04

Tags: login, motd

I'm attempting to get the MOTD to appear on login. Got an old box recently updated and running 18.04.4 LTS. The default MOTD scripts all exist in `/etc/update-motd.d/`, are set to +x and run successfully using `run-parts`.

sshd_config:

```
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
```

pam.d/sshd:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

Also no sign of a `.hushlogin` file for the user.

Comment: What does `cat /run/motd.dynamic` print ? Are your units running? --> `systemctl status motd-news.{service,timer}` ? Take a look in `systemctl cat motd-news.service` for errors. Further, did you permanently set the env variable `MOTD_SHOWN=pam` ? Proove with `echo $MOTD_SHOWN`!

Answer (score 2):

Change the sshd_config to

```
PrintMotd yes
```

and  pam.d/sshd remove or comment the following line

```
#session optional pam_motd.so noupdate
```